# CSS transition tricks

Tags: css, animation, transition, z-index

Is there a possibility to define transition only on certain change.
For example I make my div's z-index larger. I want change applied immediately(no-animation), and whenever I decrease amount of z-index it should animate.

imagine that you have some button which will open some content which have absolute position.
above of that button I have some sticky content which should be above of that button while I scrolling down. But it should be below of card that opened via button.

I have tried to use :has() pseudo selector to determined whether my button is opened.
and make its z-index from x -> x + 1;
but as my button disappeared with animation. Sticky content pops up above the button immediately after I click close button. So I would like to slow down z-index change on button to wait until content will disappear to change the buttons z-index. (I want to achieve it by using only css).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I’m struggling to understand exactly what effect you want so please give us the relevant code as a runnable snippet using the documents @disinfor has linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the first paragraph of your question, the answer is yes, you can switch a `transition` rule on and off using different classes.

In this snippet, the `.d1` style rule specifies `transition: 1.5s` and the `.d1.raised` rule specifies `transition: none`. So, when the `raised` class is added by pushing the button, no transition is used, but when it is *removed* by pushing the button a second time, a transition of 1.5 seconds is used. You’ll see that when you push the button, the red square in the left-hand set of squares comes immediately to the front (`z-index: 5`), then when you push the button again, the red square moves to the back (`z-index: 1`) slowly over a period of 1.5 seconds. Note that you need to set specific z-indexes on the other squares as well to make this transition work. Note also that because `z-index` is an *integer* value, it transitions in steps rather than smoothly.

In contrast, `opacity` transitions smoothly because it is a *decimal* value. The right-hand set of squares uses an opacity transition rather than a z-index transition.

```js
document.querySelector('.b1').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.d1, .d9').forEach(e => {
    e.classList.toggle('raised')
  })
  evt.target.innerHTML = 'push me again'
})
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 170px;
}
.d1, .d2, .d3, .d4, .d5, .d6, .d7, .d8, .d9 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}
.d1 {
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1.5s;
}
.d1.raised {
  z-index: 5;
  transition: none;
}
.d2 {
  background: green;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.d3 {
  background: blue;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.d4 {
  background: pink;
  top: 45px;
  left: 45px;
  z-index: 4;
}
.d5 {
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.d6 {
  background: green;
  top: 15px;
  left: 215px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.d7 {
  background: blue;
  top: 30px;
  left: 230px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.d8 {
  background: pink;
  top: 45px;
  left: 245px;
  z-index: 4;
}
.d9 {
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1.5s;
}
.d9.raised {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">d1</div>
<div class="d2">d2</div>
<div class="d3">d3</div>
<div class="d4">d4</div>

<div class="d5">d5</div>
<div class="d6">d6</div>
<div class="d7">d7</div>
<div class="d8">d8</div>
<div class="d9">d9</div>

<button class="b1">push me</button>
```